# Cumulative decoder/encoder

Tags: java, netty, decoder

I have been using Apache MINA and am learning Netty.  I have used the MINA cumulative encoder/decoder in the past and I am interested to see if Netty has similar functionality.  I looked through the API and did not see anything.

Comment: can you tell us what the cumulative encoder/decoder does ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the FrameDecoder [1] or ReplayingDecoder [2].

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html

[2] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/replay/ReplayingDecoder.html